# how to group my string vector in two data frame?

Tags: r

Hi: I have a simple question but it confuse me a lot. Below are my codes:

```
a <- data.frame(url = c("1","2","3","4","5"),
                id = c("a","b","c","d","e")
                 )
b <- data.frame(url = c("1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","4","4","5","5"),
                price = c(10,10,20,20,20,30,30,30,30,40,40,50,50),
                recipt=c("n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","y","y","n","n")
)
```

I want my `newdata` , which `merge b$recipt into a` and becomes:

```
>newdata
    url id recipt
    1   a   n
    2   b   n
    3   c   n
    4   d   y
    5   e   n
```

please give me some hint, thanks

Comment: Your first data set seems to be missing a recipt.

Comment: @AlexT. I am trying to use b data that can be merge/grouped by url, and then merge into my a data.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. The data in a doesn't seem to make sense if you're trying to merge the two sets. Also, these values don't appear to be unique. Surely your URLs must either be unique, or always have the same price. What conditions would you use to discard data from the merge?

Comment: I edit my questions again, please have a look @AlexT.

Comment: you could simply use `merge` for this `merge(a, unique(subset(b, select = -c(price))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
a$recipt <- sapply(1:nrow(a),function(x) b$recipt[b$url==a$url[x]][1])    

#> a
#  url id recipt
#1   1  a      n
#2   2  b      n
#3   3  c      n
#4   4  d      y
#5   5  e      n
```

Here it is assumed that the `recipt` entries are the same for any given value of `url` in `b`. If this is not the case, things become more complicated.

If you want to keep `a` unchanged and generate a new frame `newdata` with the new column, then the above code can be slightly modified in a rather trivial way:

```
newdata <- a
newdata$recipt <- sapply(1:nrow(a),function(x) b$recipt[b$url==a$url[x]][1])
```

Comment: Thanks!! This helps me a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `match`

```
  transform(a, recipt= b$recipt[match(url, b$url)])
  #    url id recipt
  #1   1  a      n
  #2   2  b      n
  #3   3  c      n
  #4   4  d      y
  #5   5  e      n
```

Or using the devel version of `data.table`.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
  library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
  setDT(a)[unique(b[c(1,3)], by='url'), on='url']
  #     url id recipt
  #1:   1  a      n
  #2:   2  b      n
  #3:   3  c      n
  #4:   4  d      y
  #5:   5  e      n
```

Comment: Thanks for give me another easy way to fix my problem. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

So I think what you want is to merge a onto b as there are multiple prices with the same url. Thus `b` is your base data frame and you want to append an id value to it. Some of the id values would be repeated.

One easy way is to do this with dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)

a <- data.frame(url = c("1","2","3","4","5"),
                id = c("a","b","c","d","e")
)
b <- data.frame(url = c("1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","4","4","5","5"),
                price = c(10,10,20,20,20,30,30,30,30,40,40,50,50),
                recipt=c("n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","n","y","y","n","n")
)

left_join(b, a, by = "url")
   url price recipt id
1    1    10      n  a
2    1    10      n  a
3    2    20      n  b
4    2    20      n  b
5    2    20      n  b
6    3    30      n  c
7    3    30      n  c
8    3    30      n  c
9    3    30      n  c
10   4    40      y  d
11   4    40      y  d
12   5    50      n  e
13   5    50      n  e
```

Comment: This is the same result as `merge(b,a)`. I don't think that it corresponds to the desired output according to the OP.

Comment: RHertel:   That's right, the output produced by "user1357015"  are not the output that I want it to. But thanks.